# Vote counts and badge's vote counts aren't the same

Tags: bug, voting

[image: Screenshot]

This seems to be a bug. I can't possibly have made 223 votes and 227!

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com

Answer (score 3):

Turns out this was due to caching.

> Thanks to @ZoestandswithUkraine and [shouldiblamecaching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: Actually, [server-side caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69172/241919), not browser-side caching.